# How to make Marquee with delay between its elements?

Tags: html

Hi, 
if I want two elements of text, and delay between them, to be **marqueed**. 
 how to code it ?
I mean:

-----> Text A ------>

-----blank (empty) for 5 seconds---

-----> Text B ------>

... again and again the same..

 
 Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer is you can't

Because marquee does not provide such facility. Alternatively you can use various third party jquery or javascript animation tools that gives the same effect as marquee and also provides customization.

Like [this](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Text-Scrolling-Plugin-for-jQuery-Marquee/)